# Remove dashbord acess form wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a wordpress website and it have multiple admin. I want to remove dashboard acess of one admin without changing his role .

I need to change dashboard access via a code . And that admin id is 8

So to hide admin bar i use the following code

```
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

        function remove_admin_bar() {
            if (get_current_user_id()==8) {
              show_admin_bar(false);
            }
       }
```

Now i want to remove his dashboard access . Please help .

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
    function prevent_adminuser_access(){
    if((get_current_user_id()==8) && is_admin() )  {
        // maybe redirect to homepage
        wp_safe_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
    }
}
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'prevent_adminuser_access' );
```